# UIAlertController con indicador de actividad al cargar JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

Estoy cargando JSON en mi `UIViewController` de la siguiente manera y necesito que me aparezca un `UIAlertController` con un `Activity Indicator` que se oculte automáticamente cuando el JSON se carga al completo.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://...com/json/...php?id=\(pasarid)").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

        if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["bandas"].array {
            self.completo.text = resData[0]["nombre"].string
            self.historia.text = resData[0]["descripcion"].string
            self.fundacion.text = resData[0]["fun"].string
            self.sede.text = resData[0]["sede"].string
            self.componentes.text = resData[0]["com"].string
            self.director.text = resData[0]["director"].string
            self.procesiones.text = resData[0]["bandas"].string
            self.asisuena.text = resData[0]["marcha"].string

            self.web = resData[0]["web"].string!
            self.facebook = resData[0]["bandas"].string!
            self.twitter = resData[0]["bandas"].string!
            self.correo = resData[0]["bandas"].string!

        }
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ***activity indicator*** lo deberías mostrar al comienzo del método `viewDidLoad` y ocultar luego de obtener el JSON en el ***completion handler*** de `Alamofire.request`.

No se si el ***completion handler*** se ejecuta en el ***main thred***, si no es así, entonces deberías hacer un `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, {...})` para ocultarlo.

Por último, para mostrar un ***activity indicator*** puedes usar por ejemplo [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Ejemplo:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    progressHUD.labelText = "Loading..."
    progressHUD.mode = .Indeterminate

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://...com/json/...php?id=\(pasarid)").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
        })
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perdona pero soy bastante nuevo en esto, ¿podrías ser un poco más concreto para poder hacerme una idea de lo que debo hacer?

Comment: @JaviRando Actualicé la respuesta con código de ejemplo...

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección!! Muchas gracias